# LookupField with more than 1 LookupValue

Tags: c#, class, model-view-controller, lookup

Hi i have the following and i was wondering if i can have two(more than 1) LookupValue under one LookupField. please assist.

```
 parameter = new LookupParameter();
        parameter.LookupField = LookupParameters.Fieldname;
        parameter.LookupValue = Value1.valuename.Code;
        parameter.TheOperator = LookupOperator.NotEqual;
        parameterList.Add(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by just change the lookup operator to "Equal" didn't have to have two LookupValues only needed one. thank you.

```
 parameter = new LookupParameter();
    parameter.LookupField = LookupParameters.Fieldname;
    parameter.LookupValue = Value1.valuename.Code;
    parameter.TheOperator = LookupOperator.Equal;
    parameterList.Add(parameter);
```